# Matlab - Storing data from a nested loop

Tags: matlab, loops

I would like to store the data from a double loop in a matrix (not a cell). 
I tried the following code (the function used in the inner loop here is just an example).

```
valuesforOPratio = zeros(41,1);
valuesforM = zeros(41,61);
NPVtotal=1;
for M = 40:100
for OPratio = 30:70;
NPVtotal = NPVtotal+1
valuesforOPratio(OPratio)=NPVtotal;
end
valuesforM(M) = valuesforOPratio
end
I get the following error:

 In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.

Error in sensitivity_opratio (line 10)
valuesforM(M) = valuesforOPratio
```

Any help on how to store the data in a matrix ? I guess this is rather easy but I am not getting there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with you code :

1/ You define `valuesforOPratio` as a `41x1` Vector. However, in the inner nested loop, the subscripts `OPratio` go from 30 to 70, meaning when you write `valuesforOPratio(OPratio)=NPVtotal;` the size of your `valuesforOPratio` vector will increase to 70.

To rectify that, you might want to either :

1. Make your `OPratio` subscript go from 1 to 41 (i.e. `for OPratio=1:41 ...`)
2. Set the right subscript in the call mentionned above (i.e. `valuesforOPratio(OPratio-29)=NPVtotal;`)

2/ When you write `valuesforM(M)=valuesforOPratio`, you are trying to put a vector (`valuesforOPratio`) in a scalar element (`valuesforM(M)`).

To rectify that, you just need to specify that you want a *whole column* of `valuesforM` to be filled with the values in `valuesforOPratio`, i.e. :

`valuesforM(:,M-39)=valuesforOPratio;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works perfectly fine. If i would change both loops to "parfor" loops would it still work the same way ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `valuesforM` is a 41 by 61 matrix. If you want to write a row or colum you should wirte `valuesforM(M:) = valuesforOPratio` or `valuesforM(:M) = valuesforOPratio`

I havent MATLAB here on my computer to check my answer, but it should help you to find the solution.

Comment: thanks, now i get "subscripted assignment dimension mismatch .... " -any idea on that ?