# How do I save double for loop whlist using a function? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have found a rolling window function online,

```
function output = createRollingWindow(vector, n)
% CREATEROLLINGWINDOW returns successive overlapping windows onto a vector
%   OUTPUT = CREATEROLLINGWINDOW(VECTOR, N) takes a numerical vector VECTOR
%   and a positive integer scalar N. The result OUTPUT is an MxN matrix,
%   where M = length(VECTOR)-N+1. The I'th row of OUTPUT contains
%   VECTOR(I:I+N-1).
l = length(vector);
m = l - n + 1;
output = vector(hankel(1:m, m:l));
end
```

From this function, I am trying to include two for loops into my code,

```
%Out of sample attempt
clear;
clc;
kk=1;%to help with recording
for q = 1:3;
    for w = 1:6;
    data(:,1) = [ 0.824178794   0.320861779 0.544464994 0.443415606 0.881589471 0.126930695 0.10758006  0.64661864  0.186043513 0.113938139 0.397832754 0.245128803 0.601561899 0.702804161 0.868598731 0.896887742 0.315118703 0.652750644 0.442618269 0.414916628 0.091210459 0.778660087 0.477795261 0.170882616 0.358117319 0.952619704 0.299335988 0.672694952 0.659587974 0.116092814 0.354043427 0.558700934 0.383720179 0.497181625 0.220384304 0.918564103 0.83692923  0.091426279 0.748032692 0.632857627 0.711075772 0.116125763 0.597741796 0.514174441 0.615460425 0.645151999 0.226984236 0.12237818  0.699570062 0.114368326 0.846111165 0.695035952 0.23948643  0.599922736 0.306768402 0.067744491 0.783072298 0.087849296 0.85992126  0.242326707 0.707444842 0.708394112 0.648583229 0.881334696 0.822010696 0.482946533 0.973389017 0.99451342  0.396172299 0.885790819 0.6547881   0.435092468 0.982999085 0.082579592 0.282836873 0.281771702 0.659658085 0.628989875 0.653124888 0.158068163 0.72719761  0.204252699 0.417000233 0.883864326 0.54291388  0.923703895 0.092945717 0.635086879 0.849531721 0.235541373 0.37923794  0.104290602 0.012590039 0.487503652 0.199704805 0.594050564 0.9801534   0.978849296 0.187787141 0.964071808 0.139609956 0.814162483 0.30894139  0.812033217 0.142302294 0.055008992 0.400725294 0.619958465 0.228309428 0.606736617 0.065623529 0.987751722 0.88678899  0.693903646 0.89933127  0.4640739   0.96584424  0.644626537 0.701417614 0.586577243 0.984983184 0.141416031 0.348001281 0.646667949 0.696233019 0.40711813];
    data(:,2) = [0.601312801    0.567678926 0.010228683 0.819126718 0.374199446 0.752227144 0.692009283 0.160297793 0.41729925  0.004383375 0.391805283 0.727950395 0.042412421 0.702262491 0.46841405  0.335453208 0.846544411 0.022669174 0.93789211  0.628081132 0.922873091 0.794009152 0.398190721 0.146860091 0.276906047 0.040990629 0.885172725 0.995618555 0.081377375 0.673312607 0.507802794 0.507211426 0.864098858 0.618331858 0.497025625 0.199872624 0.680890254 0.733198925 0.073351847 0.535303576 0.037211143 0.256505612 0.076706486 0.209499708 0.20674952  0.591840692 0.816632191 0.870881906 0.795427041 0.206113399 0.383909285 0.917927405 0.868804777 0.839985866 0.346596048 0.750367231 0.960418228 0.001626573 0.613545782 0.343902168 0.011611464 0.516205321 0.21196681  0.885751081 0.415271144 0.621481833 0.791477412 0.894585662 0.79669597  0.056652307 0.914691669 0.567923067 0.086743503 0.384397699 0.795918739 0.339847836 0.96086507  0.218898901 0.593647285 0.861695814 0.210231592 0.899967064 0.897346931 0.330684285 0.110565195 0.878917027 0.32734661  0.997426716 0.766167074 0.993337315 0.454428456 0.835946458 0.69975433  0.983277113 0.868033073 0.551361664 0.565948465 0.383959861 0.915339748 0.165000585 0.598434963 0.469557418 0.997527846 0.731639315 0.074477013 0.829399281 0.72211419  0.110424513 0.942230634 0.031584519 0.844465109 0.117074378 0.093737687 0.609404299 0.807640005 0.048202653 0.782269274 0.659084731 0.488254063 0.032889558 0.947366815 0.787888171 0.456713783 0.155336211 0.93715265  0.515620832];
    data(:,3) = [0.601312801    0.567678926 0.010228683 0.819126718 0.374199446 0.752227144 0.692009283 0.160297793 0.41729925  0.004383375 0.391805283 0.727950395 0.042412421 0.702262491 0.46841405  0.335453208 0.846544411 0.022669174 0.93789211  0.628081132 0.922873091 0.794009152 0.398190721 0.146860091 0.276906047 0.040990629 0.885172725 0.995618555 0.081377375 0.673312607 0.507802794 0.507211426 0.864098858 0.618331858 0.497025625 0.199872624 0.680890254 0.733198925 0.073351847 0.535303576 0.037211143 0.256505612 0.076706486 0.209499708 0.20674952  0.591840692 0.816632191 0.870881906 0.795427041 0.206113399 0.383909285 0.917927405 0.868804777 0.839985866 0.346596048 0.750367231 0.960418228 0.001626573 0.613545782 0.343902168 0.011611464 0.516205321 0.21196681  0.885751081 0.415271144 0.621481833 0.791477412 0.894585662 0.79669597  0.056652307 0.914691669 0.567923067 0.086743503 0.384397699 0.795918739 0.339847836 0.96086507  0.218898901 0.593647285 0.861695814 0.210231592 0.899967064 0.897346931 0.330684285 0.110565195 0.878917027 0.32734661  0.997426716 0.766167074 0.993337315 0.454428456 0.835946458 0.69975433  0.983277113 0.868033073 0.551361664 0.565948465 0.383959861 0.915339748 0.165000585 0.598434963 0.469557418 0.997527846 0.731639315 0.074477013 0.829399281 0.72211419  0.110424513 0.942230634 0.031584519 0.844465109 0.117074378 0.093737687 0.609404299 0.807640005 0.048202653 0.782269274 0.659084731 0.488254063 0.032889558 0.947366815 0.787888171 0.456713783 0.155336211 0.93715265  0.515620832];
%This is what we are trying to forecast
createRollingWindow(data(:,q), w);%This uses the function saved as createRollingWindow
sum(ans,2); %This sums the rows in the matrix, which is what I need
%YF(kk,:)=(ans);
%kk=kk+1;

    end
end
```

What I ideally need is a vector which includes the results from the for loops,

I have attempted to call this vector YF in the above code,

My question is...

How can i store the output from both loops in a matrix called  YF,

I.e. for each rolling window, 1:6, and for each data set, 1:3.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATED CODE FROM TRYING SUGGESTIONS IN COMMENT, STILL NEEDS THE FIRST FUNCTION

```
%Out of sample attempt
clear;
clc;
%kk=1;%to help with recording
YF = [];
for q = 1:3;
    for w = 1:6;
    data(:,1) = [ 0.824178794   0.320861779 0.544464994 0.443415606 0.881589471 0.126930695 0.10758006  0.64661864  0.186043513 0.113938139 0.397832754 0.245128803 0.601561899 0.702804161 0.868598731 0.896887742 0.315118703 0.652750644 0.442618269 0.414916628 0.091210459 0.778660087 0.477795261 0.170882616 0.358117319 0.952619704 0.299335988 0.672694952 0.659587974 0.116092814 0.354043427 0.558700934 0.383720179 0.497181625 0.220384304 0.918564103 0.83692923  0.091426279 0.748032692 0.632857627 0.711075772 0.116125763 0.597741796 0.514174441 0.615460425 0.645151999 0.226984236 0.12237818  0.699570062 0.114368326 0.846111165 0.695035952 0.23948643  0.599922736 0.306768402 0.067744491 0.783072298 0.087849296 0.85992126  0.242326707 0.707444842 0.708394112 0.648583229 0.881334696 0.822010696 0.482946533 0.973389017 0.99451342  0.396172299 0.885790819 0.6547881   0.435092468 0.982999085 0.082579592 0.282836873 0.281771702 0.659658085 0.628989875 0.653124888 0.158068163 0.72719761  0.204252699 0.417000233 0.883864326 0.54291388  0.923703895 0.092945717 0.635086879 0.849531721 0.235541373 0.37923794  0.104290602 0.012590039 0.487503652 0.199704805 0.594050564 0.9801534   0.978849296 0.187787141 0.964071808 0.139609956 0.814162483 0.30894139  0.812033217 0.142302294 0.055008992 0.400725294 0.619958465 0.228309428 0.606736617 0.065623529 0.987751722 0.88678899  0.693903646 0.89933127  0.4640739   0.96584424  0.644626537 0.701417614 0.586577243 0.984983184 0.141416031 0.348001281 0.646667949 0.696233019 0.40711813];
    data(:,2) = [0.601312801    0.567678926 0.010228683 0.819126718 0.374199446 0.752227144 0.692009283 0.160297793 0.41729925  0.004383375 0.391805283 0.727950395 0.042412421 0.702262491 0.46841405  0.335453208 0.846544411 0.022669174 0.93789211  0.628081132 0.922873091 0.794009152 0.398190721 0.146860091 0.276906047 0.040990629 0.885172725 0.995618555 0.081377375 0.673312607 0.507802794 0.507211426 0.864098858 0.618331858 0.497025625 0.199872624 0.680890254 0.733198925 0.073351847 0.535303576 0.037211143 0.256505612 0.076706486 0.209499708 0.20674952  0.591840692 0.816632191 0.870881906 0.795427041 0.206113399 0.383909285 0.917927405 0.868804777 0.839985866 0.346596048 0.750367231 0.960418228 0.001626573 0.613545782 0.343902168 0.011611464 0.516205321 0.21196681  0.885751081 0.415271144 0.621481833 0.791477412 0.894585662 0.79669597  0.056652307 0.914691669 0.567923067 0.086743503 0.384397699 0.795918739 0.339847836 0.96086507  0.218898901 0.593647285 0.861695814 0.210231592 0.899967064 0.897346931 0.330684285 0.110565195 0.878917027 0.32734661  0.997426716 0.766167074 0.993337315 0.454428456 0.835946458 0.69975433  0.983277113 0.868033073 0.551361664 0.565948465 0.383959861 0.915339748 0.165000585 0.598434963 0.469557418 0.997527846 0.731639315 0.074477013 0.829399281 0.72211419  0.110424513 0.942230634 0.031584519 0.844465109 0.117074378 0.093737687 0.609404299 0.807640005 0.048202653 0.782269274 0.659084731 0.488254063 0.032889558 0.947366815 0.787888171 0.456713783 0.155336211 0.93715265  0.515620832];
    data(:,3) = [0.601312801    0.567678926 0.010228683 0.819126718 0.374199446 0.752227144 0.692009283 0.160297793 0.41729925  0.004383375 0.391805283 0.727950395 0.042412421 0.702262491 0.46841405  0.335453208 0.846544411 0.022669174 0.93789211  0.628081132 0.922873091 0.794009152 0.398190721 0.146860091 0.276906047 0.040990629 0.885172725 0.995618555 0.081377375 0.673312607 0.507802794 0.507211426 0.864098858 0.618331858 0.497025625 0.199872624 0.680890254 0.733198925 0.073351847 0.535303576 0.037211143 0.256505612 0.076706486 0.209499708 0.20674952  0.591840692 0.816632191 0.870881906 0.795427041 0.206113399 0.383909285 0.917927405 0.868804777 0.839985866 0.346596048 0.750367231 0.960418228 0.001626573 0.613545782 0.343902168 0.011611464 0.516205321 0.21196681  0.885751081 0.415271144 0.621481833 0.791477412 0.894585662 0.79669597  0.056652307 0.914691669 0.567923067 0.086743503 0.384397699 0.795918739 0.339847836 0.96086507  0.218898901 0.593647285 0.861695814 0.210231592 0.899967064 0.897346931 0.330684285 0.110565195 0.878917027 0.32734661  0.997426716 0.766167074 0.993337315 0.454428456 0.835946458 0.69975433  0.983277113 0.868033073 0.551361664 0.565948465 0.383959861 0.915339748 0.165000585 0.598434963 0.469557418 0.997527846 0.731639315 0.074477013 0.829399281 0.72211419  0.110424513 0.942230634 0.031584519 0.844465109 0.117074378 0.093737687 0.609404299 0.807640005 0.048202653 0.782269274 0.659084731 0.488254063 0.032889558 0.947366815 0.787888171 0.456713783 0.155336211 0.93715265  0.515620832];
%This is what we are trying to forecast
createRollingWindow(data(:,q), w);%This uses the function saved as createRollingWindow
sum(ans,2); %This sums the rows in the matrix, which is what I need
YF = [YF, ans]
%kk=kk+1;

    end
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is...

How can i store the output from both loops in a matrix called  YF, 

I.e. for each rolling window, 1:6, and for each data set, 1:3.

Comment: Instead of `YF(kk, :)=(ans);` you can try `YF=[YF, ans]` or `YF=[YF; ans]` depending on the dimension of the vector ans. It would be better to preallocate the memory. If you know the final size of `YF` you should first set `YF=zeros(1, finalSize)`. But then you can't use `YF=[YF, ans]`. You have to insert the values by index.

Comment: I get an error when I used this, I am not sure why.

Comment: What error do you get??

Comment: Error in FileName (line 14)
YF = [YF, ans]

Comment: @TonyChivers that error is not generated by any of the code you shared. Also that is not the entire error. Please learn [ask]

Comment: Of course you need `YF = []` before the first loop

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code in the answer, this is still now working for me.

Comment: @ThomasSablik when I remove the second loop it works great, as in the problem is now with the second loop

Comment: Avoid using `ans` as a variable in your scripts, it's really bad practise and will cause you many headaches!! Assign outputs to actual variables, don't rely on `ans` being correctly assigned in your workspace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab - Storing data from a nested loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317219/matlab-storing-data-from-a-nested-loop)